# meteor fails to start server in events.js with write EOF exception

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

When I try to start a meteor project I always get this error message (on my machine only, the project is working fine on my colleague's machines):

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EOF
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:785:14)
```

Sometimes the error already shows up before mongo is stared.

In fact, I cannot start *any* project anymore ... :-(

It seems that I have a serious problem with my meteor installation.

- I tried re-installing meteor, but no effect.
- `meteor reset` --> no effect

Could it be a problem with a downloaded package? Where does meteor store the packages?

I really would appreaiate any hint what I can try to make it work again.

I'm using meteor on windows.

Comment: Also `meteor reset` does not change something